# How to use Prototype.js in DNN 6.x?

Tags: prototypejs, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 6.x which uses JQuery by default. I have a requirement to use prototype.js in some of modules that I am building. As $ variable is used by both the libraries I am getting various errors on the page. Is there a way I can use prototype in DNN 6.x without getting conflict errors?

Thanks
Dev

Answer (score 0):

You can configure jQuery not to use the $ variable. Run this before anything else, just after you've added the jQuery script:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

This requires all code using jQuery not to use $, but instead jQuery, i.e.

```
jQuery("#selector").show()
```

instead of

```
$("#selector").show()
```

You can read more about noConflict [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Comment: How to configure DNN to use Jquery in noConflict mode? Many of DNN framework components use Jquery and JqueryUI, how can I tell DNN to use Jquery in conflict mode?

Comment: By using the above noConflict() function call you tell jQuery to run in noconflict mode, which means all .js code will use a reconfigured jQuery. The problem with this is that all the scripts DNN uses have to use `jQuery` instance rather than `$`, which they might not (but, imho, should - it's a good practice).